# Working With JavaScript CallBacks

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm Trying to use a call back to close a modal progress bar, but the callback function simple doesn't work. you can see my code is quite simple

```
function filtro() {
       document.getElementById('openModal').style.display = 'block';
       //Loads data
       loaddata(function () { document.getElementById('openModal').style.display = 'block'; });
}
```

Whats is possible wrong?

Comment: What does `loaddata` do?

Comment: Changing the second 'block' to 'none' might work(?)

Comment: Before calling `loaddata` you are setting `openModal` `display = 'block'`. In the callback, you are setting it to `block` again. I'm guessing that was supposed to be `none`.

Comment: Why do you set in both cases (on start and on done) the display style to 'block'. Is 'none' what you mean in second case?

Comment: are you trying to hide the element using `...display = 'block'` ? Try `...display = 'none'`. Else try adding a `console.log('fired');` in the function to know when it's executed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks, yes i was setting the display to block twice but this was not the error, actually the loaddata function is the one that uses ajax calls (many of them) i just used ".done(function(){...});" at the end of each ajax call and it worked.